# C# coding to check a particular server is present or not in the page given by url

Tags: c#

As part of checking i need to check whether the particular server is existing in the pool of servers which are present in a particular url,how can i check by using c# code in order to make a tool??please help me

Comment: How is the pool of servers handled? (Eg. if load balancer which one.) What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Ping class:

```
        bool pingable = false;

        Ping pingObject = new Ping();

        PingReply reply = pingObject.Send("127.0.0.1");
        pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
```